# What does the Grothendieck topos tell us about the homotopy type of a space?

Tags: gn.general-topology, topos-theory

Let $M_1$, $M_2$ be two closed connected topological manifolds. We can consider the small sites of open coverings of them, and the categories of sheaves on these sites.

- what can we say about $M_1$ and $M_2$ if the sites are equivalent?
- what can we say about $M_1$ and $M_2$ if the topoi are equivanent?

Comment: This doesn't address your question, but given the different unregistered accounts you keep opening https://mathoverflow.net/users/140276/m-for-motive https://mathoverflow.net/users/140971/m-for-motive https://mathoverflow.net/users/140961/m-for-motive https://mathoverflow.net/users/140893/m-for-motive would it not make sense to register a single account?

Comment: The topos $\mathcal E$ of sheaves on a topological space $X$ determines the locale of open subsets of $X$ as the Heyting algebra of subobjects of $1$ in $\mathcal E$. That locale, in turn, determines the space $X$ as long as $X$ is sober, which manifolds are.